# Accessing pgsql db set in cygwin from qgis installed on windows through osgeo4w, possible?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, windows-8, osgeo4w, cygwin

As the title of this question, I want to know if it is possible to access a PostgreSQL database set in cygwin (version 9) from QGis installed in Windows 8.1 through the OSgeo4W application, is that possible? if so, could you explain some simple steps to do so?

Thanks for any pointers,

Comment: What do you mean a postgresSQL database in cygwin?  Isn't the server just installed on the machine?

Comment: I use postgresql in cygwin, my db is there, that is what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use cygwin all the time.  However, I elected to use [Starting PostgreSQL in windows without install](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html) and the binaries from [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) and [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/windows_downloads).  That allowed me to push the limits with recent developments.

That being said, Cygwin, MS Windows, Linux, and Mac are just database clients or database servers. You'd want to follow some [sort of configuration guide.](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01)  Set you pg_hba.conf and environment variables.  You can then use a cygwin client to access any Postgresql database that you have rights and network access to.  You may receive warnings about an older client accessing a newer database server but if you are using simple selects, then it doesn't mater.

- In some cases, I will run the SDKsetup.bat shell for my gdal install, then run the script to setup the psql client's environment.  It works like a champ!
- If I have a wide result set to look at, then I have a script that sets the environment and runs PGAdminIII.

Keep telling yourself, "qgis is just a database client."  You don't have to run a database client like most people expect.  In my case, I've gone wacko with an older Fedora Linux client/database, MS Windows client/database, and Red Hat Enterprise 6 client/database.  I've been able to attach data from any of these databases in qgis. qgis against a cygwin database with the correct pg_hba.conf settings should be no different!